# "A custom listen action is restricted. Please use the global listen action instead"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook app, i created the action:listen.
Now when i go trie to edit the properties of this action it gives me this error:

Restricted custom action.

A custom Listen action is restricted. Please use the global Listen action instead.

Does any one know what this error means, and how do i fix it?

I tried different actions related to my app, and still giving me the same error.

Anyone please help. :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “A custom Listen action is restricted. Please use the global Listen action instead.”
>
> Does any one know what this error means,

You can not have your own custom actions for build-in action types. And even if your custom action was approved some time ago, Facebook will require you to migrate to the build-in one whenever they come up with a new build-in one that conflicts with your custom one.

> and how do i fix it?

Switch to using the [build-in *listen* action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#listen).

Comment: Ok, i understand.  How do i switch to the build in acction.

Comment: Delete your existing like action, and make a new one – this time when you start to enter 'like' as your action’s name, Facebook will bring a flyout menu offering you the built-in one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a story choose the action as Listening and then click on Edit Tenses after that edit it according to your needs.